# Vuetify how to move a card to the bottom right corner of an overlay

Tags: html, vue.js, overlay, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Have been struggling quite a bit trying to position a card on an overlay using vuetify.

I have the following code:

```
<v-app id="app"> 
<v-card width="450" max-height="100">
    <v-img max-height="400" src="https://picsum.photos/450/450">
      <v-overlay absolute>
        <v-card flat color="transparent">
          <v-card-text
            class="white--text font-weight-black"
            :class="headingClass"
            >Center</v-card-text
          >
          <v-card-subtitle class="white--text" :class="subtitleClass">Center</v-card-subtitle>

        </v-card>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>Bottom Right</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
      </v-overlay >
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
 </v-app>
```

I have tested adding the classes

```
justify-end
align-end
```

but none of those was able to get my card (the one with the "Bottom Right" text) moved to the right or bottom.

I tried using the vuetify grid but was also not successful.

I've placed the code also on codepen under the following link
https://codepen.io/carluri/pen/jObPOMK

Would anyone know how to move that black card to the bottom right corner of the overlay?

Any help is appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to revise your markup first. As it stands now, the only way to do what you want would be to work with the absolutely positioned elements within `<v-overlay>` which isn't very responsive-friendly. However, if you don't really mind that, you can check out my fork of your pen here -> https://codepen.io/tkd21/pen/yLYNgOq

Comment: Thanks @TKD21 this is useful for now, but I agree is probably not the best. Would you have a better suggestion so that what I want to do is more responsive friendly? Basically, I have a card with an image, want to put some text on top of the image so for it to be read easily I need to put an overlay on the image for better contrast. There will be some text at the center and a small text at the bottom right to provide info about the image. If there's a better way of doing this than with the markup I'm showing I'll be happy to implement it. Cheers!!!

Comment: One dirty trick I can think of is to try to separate the "Bottom Right" element from the other two - have it in its own `<v-overlay>`. Position your "Bottom Right" element by working on the second overlay with classes like `align-end` and `justify-end`. Then set the second overlay's `opacity` attribute to 0 (default value is 0.46) as mentioned in the Vuetify documentation for `<v-overlay>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of this with some flexboxes.

Example:

```
<v-app id="app">
  <v-card width="450" max-height="100">
    <v-img max-height="400" src="https://picsum.photos/450/450">
      <v-overlay absolute>
        <div class="d-flex fill-height" style="flex-direction:column">
          <div class="d-flex fill-height align-center justify-center">
            <v-card flat color="transparent">
              <v-card-text class="white--text font-weight-black" :class="headingClass">Center</v-card-text>
              <v-card-subtitle class="white--text" :class="subtitleClass">Center</v-card-subtitle>
            </v-card>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <div class="pa-3">Text bottom right</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-overlay>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</v-app>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/alexanderjanke/pen/ExVPaPx)